# Windows batch file name manipulation

Tags: regex, windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Alright, I'm sure this is a bit of a niche question, but I'm hoping someone can help.

The OS we're dealing with is Windows NT 4.0.

What I need to do is create a batch file that reads in all the Jounal.x (where x is a number greater than 0 and less than 32) files in a folder.  Then, I need it to rename each file in the format EJ-REG-X.100.

My biggest problem, I think, is I'm a little fuzzy on the variable syntax and regular expressions for DOS.  Here's what code I've tried so far

```
FOR /R %%g IN (C:\testbatch\transfer\Journal.*) DO (set regnum=%%g, ren Journal.* EJ-REG-%regnum%.100)
```

Let me know if there's any more information I can provide.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,31) do (
    set "new=00%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "new=!new:~-3!"
    ren "C:\testbatch\transfer\Journal.%%a" "EJ-REG-!new!.100"
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a bunch!  Question though, for a bit of icing on the cake, is there anyway I could put leading zeros on the number?  So Journal.1 would be EJ-REG-001.100 and Journal.10 would be EJ-REJ-010.100?

Answer (score 0):

The /R is for récursive search and you don't use it
so remove it

%%g in your loop and BTW regnum contain the full file path

so start to remove the path and the file name to keep only the extension using %%~xg
by doing that regnum will only contain the file extension
so it will be :

```
FOR /R C:\testbatch\ %%g IN (Journal.*) DO (          
 set ext = %%~xg
 set ext = %ext:. =%
 ren %%g EJ-REG-%ext%.100)
```

Comment: There is also an unwanted dot in `%%~xg`, you know?

Comment: yes you are right, I edited my answer , cannot try but it should work.

Comment: Sorry, it can't work. Inside a code block you need `delayed expansion` and `!variables!`.